# How do you write a literal string in a Webmatrix Helper?

Tags: webmatrix

I've tried getting the following helper to work...but I'm scratching my head.

```
@helper SimpleHelper()
{
    string message;
    message="<b>Hello</b>";
    @message
}
```

The text comes out improperly encoded. With the lt; and gt; instead of the html tags.

Neither WriteLiteral(message) or @:message work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Html.Raw() helper in Razor to display that as an un-encoded string.

Here's the [Razor quick-reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) that Phil Haack put together recently.